# How to get native system call address

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

On Linux I'm trying to determine which system calls were hooked (syscall hooking) and which ones were not. I need answers to the following questions:

1. How can I read the address of a hooked system call from userspace (with root access)?
2. How can I obtain the address of the original system call?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The system call table is stored at sys_call_table[]
Below is assembly code to enter system call in linux kenrel, entry.S:

```
sysenter_do_call:
425         cmpl $(NR_syscalls), %eax
426         jae syscall_badsys
427         call *sys_call_table(,%eax,4)
428         movl %eax,PT_EAX(%esp)
429         LOCKDEP_SYS_EXIT
430         DISABLE_INTERRUPTS(CLBR_ANY)
431         TRACE_IRQS_OFF
432         movl TI_flags(%ebp), %ecx
433         testl $_TIF_ALLWORK_MASK, %ecx
434         jne sysexit_audit
```

As the sys_call_table is at kernel space, userland program can not access this symbol. You will have to write a kernel module. In it, you can print out the addresses stored at sys_call_table[] vector array.

Comment: Actually, as far as my knowledge goes, sys_call_table is not exported to the modules in recent(not that recent tbh, 2.6.something Linux kernels), so he cannot do that.